# how to query a #TempTable in a LinkedServer

Tags: sql

I have created a #TempTable in a remote server.
I added the remote server to my server using sp_addlinkedserver

when i tried to query the #TempTable  like

Select * from RemoteServer..tempdb.dbo.#TempTable i receive an error

database name 'tempdb' ignored referencing object in tempdb

can someone help how to query a #TempTable in a LinkedServer

Answer (score 4):

Temp tables are only available to the session that created them. You cannot make use of #Temp tables between sessions. Create a "real" table and query that.